# Exit render script on user input

Tags: scripting

I have a batch rendering script that could take hours to complete. It would be nice to have a way to abort the rendering loop if the user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd> , instead of having to kill the Blender process like we do today.

Is it possible to do this? I already tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> , and it did not work.

Comment: Ctrl-C crunched into system console may stop the script.

Comment: @batFINGER Already tried that, the script keeps going, although the console says some exception was raised because of the keypress, so it was acknowledged. But I was unable to catch it to exit.

Comment: Sometimes multiple times does the trick.  Perhaps post the scriptl